# DB Structure for A category hasMany attachments

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So, I have been struggling with this problem. in a hasMany relationship, Laravel is expecting me to make the foreign key in the attachment table which is wrong for my DB structure, I should have it in the category table instead.

When I do

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('attachments')->get();

    return $this->success(ApiResponseMessage::SUCCESS, $categories);
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 
1054 Unknown column 'attachments.category_id' in 'where clause'
(SQL: select * from `attachments` where `attachments`.`category_id` = 1
and `attachments`.`category_id` is not null) in file 
F:\xampp\htdocs\svysh\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 671
```

Category

```
class Category extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug'
    ];

    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Attachment');
    }
}


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('width');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Attachment

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'url', 'width', 'height', 'attachment_id'
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->integer('attachment_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('attachment');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: @linktoahref is right. Your  DB should be structured as he mentioned below, not like you have it currently.

Comment: Attachment does not only belong to categories they also belong to products, users and attributes. If i add an id for each of the relationships in the attachment model at most 1 fill be filled out which defies all the rule of an RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

Your database design is wrong as per your requirements, since category `hasMany` attachments / attachments `belongsTo` category, the attachments table should contain a `category_id` column.

Your `attachments` table schema should be like below:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('width');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and there is no need of `attachment_id` in the `categories` table schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: As per OP's comment

> Attachment does not only belong to categories they also belong to products, users and attributes

In that case, adjust the `attachments` table schema to be in accordance with [`one-to-many polymorphic`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations) relationships

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('attachments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('url');
        $table->string('width');
        $table->string('height');
        $table->integer('attachable_id');
        $table->string('attachable_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and add the respective method definitions in the model.

```
class Attachment extends Model
{

    /**
     * Get the owning attachable model.
     */
    public function attachable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
  
    /**
     * Get all the Category's attachments.
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Attachment', 'attachable');
    }
}
```

Comment: is right. This is how your DB should be structured.

Comment: Attachment does not only belong to categories they also belong to products, users and attributes. If i add an id for each of the relationships in the attachment model at most 1 fill be filled out which defies all the rule of an RDBMS

Comment: That information wasn't provided in your question. In that case you might want to adjust your database schema to be in accordance to https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @linktoahref In a case where the same attachment is used with all of these models would polymorphic relationships work? for ex the same image is used in products, users and attributes

Comment: Yes, even though the image is same, the type of the image(attachment) would differ.